# Just to be sure, the downloads at bitcoincore.org are the safer ones?

Tags: bitcoin-core, json-rpc

(more than bitcoin.org?)

And a few more questions regarding this:

1. Why did they change the naming of the versions from 0.xx to xx.0? (latest update changed from 0.21 to 22.0).
2. Why they did not add the docs for the RPC API of version 22.0?
3. Will they update the API to use JSON-RPC version 2.0?

**This is the same question divided to sub-questions that are related so please don't delete.

Comment: For the version change see https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/20223.

Answer (score 1):

> **the downloads at bitcoincore.org are the safer ones?**

https://bitcoincore.org is the website where developers of bitcoin-core place ready to use executables you can download.

I wouldn't characterise https://bitcoin.org as unsafe but nowadays I would prefer to download executables from https://bitcoincore.org

Some might argue that it is safer still to download *and carefully inspect* source code from https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin and then compile it yourself.

Whatever you do you should take care to test the checksums and/or digital signatures, making sure you don't get the expected values or keys from the same download source.